# Import field from other forms on info path

Tags: infopath, import, template

I create a new list in SharePoint 2010 and start edit the form in info path
 and now I want to import part of the fields from other info path template( already exist) 
is that possible ?

Thanks 
Almog

Answer (score 0):

this cannot be performed,

Infopath forms can only contain fields from the SharePoint list

something you can do is Add the section control and formatting rules to hide or show fields.

If you want to draw data from another list you have to create lookup fields.